# Embed Youtube code is not working in Pardot email

Tags: html, youtube, pardot

I'm trying to embedded a youtube video in a Pardot email. But I got a message error: "An error occurred.
Try watching this video on www.youtube.com, or enable JavaScript if it is disabled in your browser."

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The majority of email clients don't display video (this is an email client challenge and not one with Pardot specifically). You may want to consider a Call To Action in your email that directs the reader to a page with the video embedded.

https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/a_how_to_guide_to_embedding_html5_video_in_email/